# Block commenting in NetBeans IDE java editor

Tags: comments, netbeans-8

I have got the following code snippet written in java editor of NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 that should be multi-line commented in such a way that enables me to fold/collapse the commented portion.

```
void changeGear ( int newValue ) {
    gear = newValue;
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got what you mean try the following.

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="comment">
// Your multiline comment here
// </editor-fold>
```

Comment: Yes, boss!!! It worked fine but not the way I wanted it to be through. Very nice job indeed - really appreciate answering questions within 4 minutes it has been posted.

Answer (score 0):

Do You mean like this? You can easy click on the + or -

[image: a busy cat]
or
[image: a busy cat]

Comment: The first answer worked for me. Thanks for the concern.